# How to package CocoaPods dependencies in iOS ANE

Tags: ios, objective-c, actionscript-3, air, ane

I'm trying to create an iOS GoogleMaps ANE, but i'm having troubles with the resulting packaged ANE.

I'm able to successfully create the ANE, but when i try to create an IPA using the resulting ANE, i get a "Id: file was built for unsupported file format" error:

[image]

In order to use GoogleMaps in objective-c, a CocoaPod dependency must be downloaded, so this must be a packaging problem.

The question is, What is the correct way to package a CocoaPod in an ANE?

My current platformOtions.xml contains the following code:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/18.0"> 

<sdkVersion>7.0.0</sdkVersion> 
<linkerOptions> 
    <option>-rpath @executable_path/Frameworks</option>
</linkerOptions> 
<packagedDependencies> 
    <packagedDependency>libPods.a</packagedDependency>
    <packagedDependency>Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework</packagedDependency>
</packagedDependencies> 
</platform>
```

This the ANE package:
[image]

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You are trying to mix two different ARCHs, AMD64 and armv7. You need to package the armv7 libraries that you built and are loading in your ANE, not the one's built for OS-X 64-bit

Comment: How?, i think i'm loading the generated .a files.